# How to send data as argument from web application to c++ and back?

Tags: javascript, python, c++, hybrid, google-earth-engine

Let me give you some context for this question.

I joined to a halfway project in which we need to produce some coordinates data based on certain parameters defined by GEOTIFF maps. I need to get an array of coordinates from the map, send them to proccesing, and retrieve a new array of coordinates which then I'll show in a Gmap.

We can get the arrays, we can process them, and we can get the new array back, but everything on separated instances and never as a unique application. Which is our main goal.

My only problem is, the algorithms to generate the second array are running in a separate c++ program while the interface to generate the first array is hosted as a web application running jquery, google earth engine and google maps API's in python 2.7 runtime. We need to communicate these two in order to get a unique app, and I never faced this kind of implementation before.

So my question can be divided as:

1. How can I send an array of data from a Web Application as an argument for a C++ routine?
2. How can I retrieve the resultant array from the C++ routine?

The main issue is that I don't know how to approach to this kind of implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use ICAP protocol.

Comment: Gonna check it out, thank you!